# HTML including CSS using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, dynamic, url-rewriting

I am trying to build a one-page dynamic site and I've hit a roadblock. Since URLs like:

```
index.php?page=Tutorials&Article=0
```

aren't really all that pretty, I decided to use .htaccess to rewrite URLs, in this case like so:

```
Tutorials/Articles/0
```

But that means most of my includes won't work since I use paths relative to the root path of the site:

```
js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
```

I've tried to work around these by using the following code included at the beginning of index.php:

```
$str = dirname(__FILE__);
$str = str_replace('\\','/',$str);//since i'm using localhost for development, the paths contain backwards slahses so I replace them
$str.='/';
define('ROOT_DIR', $str);
```

And including everytinhg with php:

```
echo ROOT_DIR.'js/jquery';
```

But this aproach doesn't seem to work very well, even though the paths apear to be generated ok:

```
<script src="C:/xampp/htdocs/Tzeny/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

My question is can you help me find another solution to include my files corectly or to make my solution work?

For first pages it works, so:

```
Tzeny/Tutorials
```

works but

```
Tzeny/Tutorials/Categories/0
```

doesn't include anything. I used both /Tzeny/ and /. Any more ideas please? Or should I just go back to normal URLs?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use absolute path. Example :
if your domain is www.domain.com/Tzeny/index.php?page=Tutorials&Article=0
into each file like index you need include scripts like that :

```
<script src="/Tzeny/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Just use absolute urls

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

If you're not using virtual hosts for your local development, you can make the root of your urls a variable - so that the same code works irrespective of where you run it

Example:

```
<?php //pseudo code
if (on localhost) {
    $root = '/' . dirname(__FILE__); // example
} else {
    $root = '/';
}
?>

<script src="<?= $root ?>js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the index.php is on the document root your code would work by setting

```
$ROOT = "/";
```

if it's being served out of a directory you can try a

```
$ROOT = "/".str_replace(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],"/", '',$ROOT);
```

hope this helps.